# T-Sql Query : how to make two conditions met in one record and not one only

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query the following query :

```
select Opp.[ID], Opp.ContactID, Opp.RTSID, Opp.[ProjectName],
       CONVERT(varchar, Opp.[PurchaseDate], 103) as PurchaseDate,
       CONVERT(varchar,Opp.[SubmissionDate],103) as SubmissionDate,
       Opp.[Cost], Opp.[Selling], Opp.[CompanyName], Opp.[Telephone], 
       Opp.[Fax], Con.[ContactName], Con.[ContactPosition], 
       Con.[ContactDirectPhone], Con.[ContactMobile], Con.[ContactEmail],
       lookup.DescriptionEn as ProjectStatus, Opp.[Wining], Opp.[Remark],
       Opp.[CustomerReference], Sales.FName + ' ' + Sales.LName as SalesMan
from Opportunities Opp inner join Sales on Opp.Sales_Num = Sales.Sales_Num
     left join
       (select MINOR, DescriptionEn from lookup_table where MAJOR = '1') lookup
       ON lookup.MINOR = Opp.ProjectStatus
     left join
       (select ID, ContactName, ContactPosition, ContactDirectPhone, ContactMobile,
                   ContactEmail from Contacts) Con ON Con.ID = Opp.ContactID
where (lookup.DescriptionEn = @ProjectStatus or @ProjectStatus ='-1') and 
      (Opp.Sales_Num = @SalesMan or @SalesMan ='-1') and
      (Opp.Selling >= @Selling or @Selling ='0') and 
      (lookup.MINOR <> '7' and datediff(day , Opp.SubmissionDate , getdate()) < 30 )
End
```

The last Line which conntains Condition and (lookup.MINOR <> '7' or .......)
doesn't work as expected it either gets the records where MINOR <> '7' or other

I want to specify the ***two condition to met in one record only***

How to do that?

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause has `lookup.MINOR <> '7' AND ...` not `OR`. I think you need to simplify your query to show only the parts you are having trouble with. There's a commented out `JOIN`, is that wanted or not? Post the most simple query that shows the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
(lookup.MINOR <> '7' and datediff(day , Opp.SubmissionDate , getdate()) < 30 )
```

by

```
(lookup.MINOR <> '7' OR datediff(day , Opp.SubmissionDate , getdate()) < 30 )
```

Comment: I tried that On another simple query ... and it worked .
but it didn't work in this query .. can you
tell what's wrong with it ...

Comment: I figured it out guys .. Sorry
I change the Lookup.MINOR to Opp.ProjectStatus
and it worked. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Use **AND** instead of **OR**.

Comment: The OR worked in another simple query ...
but here, it didn't .. can you tell what's wrong here in this query
beside, there is no OR, it's AND..

Comment: If something **accidentally** goes right, it is not the sign, that you do it right

Comment: I figured it out guys .. Sorry
I change the Lookup.MINOR to Opp.ProjectStatus
and it worked. Thanks for the help